# Fatal error: Call to a member function toCurrency()

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, fatal-error

After login in the backend, sometimes (not always) I've this error appearing in the dashboard screen.

[image]

It's very strange and I really don't know where to look. I tried to disable all plugins, clear the cache etc.. but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

In magento c.e 1.9, **toCurrency()** *does not exiting* at `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency` class .That why  create issue.

May be ,in your system  there have ***custom code /or 3rd party extension***  which call this function using code like:

*`Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->toCurrency();`*

**You need to remove this code from your system**

Comment: Thank you Amit. I checked all the code, I found that one extension is calling the function ->toCurrency() but if I disable it, both from configuration and from the xml file, clear the cache etc.. the error remain.

Comment: Please clear cache properly.May  be cache not  clear properly at system.